# componentDidUpdate causing infiinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I have been working on a small todo application to learn and get my head around some react. Everything has been going according to plan up until I started with the completed section of the application. The problem I am trying to solve is probably pretty simple, however, I cannot seem to wrap my head around what is going on. What I am trying to do is invoke my **createCompletedList** method so I can create all of the items that have been completed. Although, when the method is invoked in the **componentDidUpdate** method it creates an infinite loop that crashes the browser. Is there any way that I can call the **createCompletedList** method that is safe from this kind of behaviour?

Any sort of advice or information would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Completed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
      completedItems: []
    };

    this.checkIndex = this.checkIndex.bind(this);
    this.createCompletedList = this.createCompletedList.bind(this);
  }

  checkIndex(event) {
    console.log("index value is " + this.props.indexValue);
  }

  createCompletedList() {
    const completedIndex = this.props.indexValue;
    const completedArray = this.state.completedItems;

    if (completedIndex) {
      completedArray.push(this.props.arrayItems[completedIndex]);
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return { completedItems: completedArray };
      });
    }

    console.log(this.state.completedItems);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.createCompletedList();
  }

  render() {
    let completedArray = this.state.completedItems;

    const retrieveList = completedArray.map((elm, index, arr) => {
      return (
        <div className="check-list-row checked" key={index}>
          {elm}
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div
        className={this.props.isTaskChecked ? "completed-container" : "hide"}>
        <div className="completed-row">
          <h1>Completed</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          {retrieveList}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Completed;
```

Comment: You should not use the `setState` function within the `componentDidUpate`  function (and you have there a call to a function that uses the `setState` one).

Comment: @Edward what if you call your `createCompletedList()` just after render.

Comment: @abdul That also causes an infinite loop, unfortunately.

Comment: `this.setState((prevState) => {return {completedItems: completedArray` `};});`  try this

Comment: @abdul No luck :(

Comment: since the value doesn't depend by the previous state i think you should just use `this.setState({completedItems: completedArray})`

Comment: @abdul I have tried that, I believe the issue lies when the method is invoked in the **componentDidUpdate** method, when I try the shouldComponentUpdate it doesn't result in an infinite loop but the before creates unwanted effects in that it will add two of the same items to my **completedArray**.

Comment: yeah using `setState` will update your component resulting in a call to componentDidUpdate which subsequently calls setState again resulting in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `this.setState()` will always cause an update. You can use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` to determine whether or not to actually update. By default this method always returns `true`. Compare `nextState.completedItems` to `this.state.completedItems` and return `false` if you don't want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Do not update state in componentDidUpdate method.

If you wont to update your state in this method you must compare at first you current state with your prev state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 if(JSON.stringify(prevState) !== JSON.stringify(this.state)) {
   ///your code....
 }


}
```

Or compare it another functions or libraries like lodash.

Comment: Hey artem,im wondering if this kind of object comparison is valid, i.e if state includes function.

Comment: @Jan Ciołek First argument in state if not object is function - updater, which helps to update the state of component. When state did update this function finished it job.